# Google maps geocoding API inconsistent

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I have a server application that calls the google maps geocoding API at http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json

I experience that when the server application invokes such an URL, the response is sometimes ZERO_RESULTS.

If I take the exact same URL and paste in a browser, I get a valid result back.

Any ideas to what differences can cause this? HTTP headers? Something else?

Comment: whats an example URL for this? I haven't seen that happen.

Comment: Also: Your code that calls the API?

Comment: Very late but in case someone else comes across this, the answer is probably Google's soft rate limiting as described in the API docs.

Comment: Same thing happening for me

Answer (score 0):

In the link you provided it is missing the address, components, latlng or place_id parameters, besides the Google Map API KEY.

You need at least one of the parameters and the Key to get a proper response.

e.g.

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?place_id=ChIJ1xwGTLE1K4gRmzFDd_1HzPc&key=xxx

Just add your KEY and it should work.